# Java "loses" timezone in Centos 7

Tags: java, linux, timezone

We have an issue happening on a CentOS 7 x64 server running Java 8u74 x64.

About once every 6-10 weeks. The running JVM seems to "loose" its timezone setting for a few seconds.

The server timezone is Australia/Perth (GMT+8) but for a few seconds, the logs print the date without timezone data (as if travelling back in time 8 hours) and then it is fine again.

Normally the logs print:

```
2016-08-30T09:57:59.811+0800
```

But during a few minutes the logs shows:

```
2016-08-30T09:57:59.811+0000 (ending in +0000 as in GMT)
```

Checks performed:

1. JVM running with `-Duser.timezone=Australia/Perth`
2. `ntpd on`
3. `yum update tzdata` done
4. `yum update ntp` done
5. `yum update tzdata` done
6. server started with `TZ=Australia/Perth` environment variable
7. `zdump -v /etc/localtime`

zdump output seems a bit strange

When I run `zdump -v /etc/localtime` I get the following:

```
/etc/localtime  -9223372036854775808 = NULL

/etc/localtime  -9223372036854689408 = NULL

/etc/localtime  Sat Nov 30 16:16:35 1895 UTC = Sat Nov 30 23:59:59 1895 LMT isdst=0 gmtoff=27804

/etc/localtime  Sat Nov 30 16:16:36 1895 UTC = Sun Dec  1 00:16:36 1895 AWST isdst=0 gmtoff=28800
...
```

About 25 more correct looking like entries

```
...
/etc/localtime  Sat Mar 28 17:59:59 2009 UTC = Sun Mar 29 02:59:59 2009 AWDT isdst=1 gmtoff=32400

/etc/localtime  Sat Mar 28 18:00:00 2009 UTC = Sun Mar 29 02:00:00 2009 AWST isdst=0 gmtoff=28800

/etc/localtime  9223372036854689407 = NULL

/etc/localtime  9223372036854775807 = NULL
```

Are those NULLs at the top and bottom an issue?

Any ideas as to what else could be causing the issue?

---

UPDATE

---

All right, issue occured again, this time the clock on the centos box was 3 hours behind and ntpd seem to have crashed.

Ok, check this out

```
[root@xotica admin]# date
Fri Oct 21 19:53:58 AWST 2016
[root@xotica admin]# service ntpd status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  ntpd.service
● ntpd.service - Network Time Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/ntpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2016-10-21 16:56:42 AWST; 2h 57min ago
 Main PID: 32012 (code=exited, status=255)

Oct 21 16:56:35 xotica.dyndns.org ntpd[32012]: 202.127.210.37 interface 192.168.1.200 -> (none)
Oct 21 16:56:39 xotica.dyndns.org ntpd[32012]: Listen normally on 6 enp0s3 192.168.1.200 UDP 123
Oct 21 16:56:39 xotica.dyndns.org ntpd[32012]: new interface(s) found: waking up resolver
Oct 21 16:56:40 xotica.dyndns.org ntpd[32012]: 0.0.0.0 0628 08 no_sys_peer
Oct 21 16:56:41 xotica.dyndns.org ntpd[32012]: Listen normally on 7 enp0s3 fe80::a00:27ff:fea0:ecd8 UDP 123
Oct 21 16:56:41 xotica.dyndns.org ntpd[32012]: new interface(s) found: waking up resolver
Oct 21 16:56:42 xotica.dyndns.org ntpd[32012]: 0.0.0.0 0617 07 panic_stop +8960 s; set clock manually within 1000 s.
Oct 21 16:56:42 xotica.dyndns.org systemd[1]: ntpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Oct 21 16:56:42 xotica.dyndns.org systemd[1]: Unit ntpd.service entered failed state.
Oct 21 16:56:42 xotica.dyndns.org systemd[1]: ntpd.service failed.
[root@xotica admin]# service ntpd restart
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart  ntpd.service
[root@xotica admin]# date
Fri Oct 21 22:23:55 AWST 2016
[root@xotica admin]# service ntpd status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  ntpd.service
● ntpd.service - Network Time Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/ntpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2016-10-21 19:54:28 AWST; 2h 33min ago
  Process: 32404 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/ntpd -u ntp:ntp $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 32405 (ntpd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/ntpd.service
           └─32405 /usr/sbin/ntpd -u ntp:ntp -g

Oct 21 19:54:28 xotica.dyndns.org ntpd[32405]: Listen normally on 2 lo 127.0.0.1 UDP 123
Oct 21 19:54:28 xotica.dyndns.org ntpd[32405]: Listen normally on 3 enp0s3 192.168.1.200 UDP 123
Oct 21 19:54:28 xotica.dyndns.org ntpd[32405]: Listen normally on 4 lo ::1 UDP 123
Oct 21 19:54:28 xotica.dyndns.org ntpd[32405]: Listen normally on 5 enp0s3 fe80::a00:27ff:fea0:ecd8 UDP 123
Oct 21 19:54:28 xotica.dyndns.org ntpd[32405]: Listening on routing socket on fd #22 for interface updates
Oct 21 19:54:30 xotica.dyndns.org ntpd[32405]: 0.0.0.0 c016 06 restart
Oct 21 19:54:30 xotica.dyndns.org ntpd[32405]: 0.0.0.0 c012 02 freq_set kernel -15.236 PPM
Oct 21 19:54:30 xotica.dyndns.org ntpd[32405]: 0.0.0.0 c61c 0c clock_step +8960.294249 s
Oct 21 22:23:50 xotica.dyndns.org ntpd[32405]: 0.0.0.0 c614 04 freq_mode
Oct 21 22:23:51 xotica.dyndns.org ntpd[32405]: 0.0.0.0 c618 08 no_sys_peer
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Isn't the time the same in these... what are you talking about?

Comment: @3kings No it isn't the same, the OP clearly said that the time zones were different and they are different.

Comment: +0`8`00 vs +0`0`00

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Please do not post paraphrased or re-typed log entries (I assume the asterisks are your hilighting).  Copy/paste _verbatim_ from the log showing a few entries prior to the "problem", through a few entries past the end of the problem.  Post the COMPLETE lines from the log. Without at least that your question is not meaningful.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Yeah but the times are the same? It's not obviously the problem.

Comment: @3kings `09:57` in GMT+08:00 is *not* the same time as `09:57` in GMT+00:00

Comment: Is it a few seconds or a few minutes that the time is off (you make both statements). Are you sure that the time is off (and it's not a log format error)? Have you checked other system log files around the same time? If the time is off there too, then it's not a Java problem but a problem with Linux. Otherwise, it *may be* a Java problem but it's hard to pinpoint with the information you've given.

Comment: Sorry Gents, just edited the question to make it more clear that during the issue the java logs show: +0000 at the end of the date.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Other applications seem fine. For example, at the time of the issue, the mysql logs showed the correct date (8pm) while the JVM was thinking it was noon.

Comment: We have had this issue happening in other GlassFish instances also running CentOS 6 and 7 and previously some of the checks performed (as described in the question) sorted the issue. Does anyone believe that the timezone data bundled in Java8u74 could be too old and needs updating?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt it is not a log formatting issue only. There is a batch job that should only run at 12 noon and when the issue occurs, it runs incorrectly at 8pm. I am not sure if it lasts for a few seconds or a few minutes but I know that the JVM is fine and the users use the system normally after that.

Comment: Added zdump output to question

Comment: @pranahata Have you done as Jim Garrison asked and posted *actual* log quotes? Did you really see the same time-of-day (…09:57:59.811…) printed a second time *minutes* apart but with different offsets? Or did the time-of-day change by the same number of hours as the offset changed?

Comment: (1) ntp is irrelevant; 'network' time is zoneless. (2) the 2 first and 2 last lines of `zdump -v` are explained on the man page. (3) are you using CentOS-packaged **openjdk**, Oracle, or something else? (4) I can;t confirm 7, but on 6 java-1.8.0-openjdk* uses a different package `tzdata-java.noarch` in `/usr/share/javazi` NOT `tzdata.noarch` in `/usr/share/zoneinfo`.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 using the oracle jre, would it be using tzdata-java.noarch too as java 8 is supposed to be based on openjdk? Thanks

Comment: Both Oracle packages and OpenJDK packages for a distro or system are based on _mostly_ the same source, with relatively small additions and modifications, but the package organization is not determined by the source. I know the Oracle 'tar' packages are entirely selfcontained and don't refer to anything else; I don't know about the 'rpm' ones. See if `/usr/lib/jvm/$fullname/jre/lib//tzdb.dat`is file or symlink and if so the target, then `yum whatprovides` to see what package it comes from.

Comment: Hi @dave_thompson_085, just checked and it is a normal file (not a symlink).

Comment: @BasilBourque sorry for the late reply, yes, I have seen the logs printing the exact same time but with different GMT offset. One line saying: [2016-09-16T14:10:35.506+0800] next line saying [2016-09-16T14:10:35.506+0000]

Comment: That makes no sense. If the time zone were being changed (*very* possible) the time-of-day should have changed along with it. That’s why Garrison and I are asking you to find and copy/paste *actual* logs rather than rely on your memory.

Comment: Ok, is just happened again on the 29th. The logs have already rotated but I'll configure them now so I don't loose them the next time it happens. Thank you @BasilBourque Thank you Jim Garrison I appreciate your help.

Comment: Ok, happened again, updated question